# Additional decimal places not showing up in EditText. Android Studio + Wear OS

Tags: android, android-edittext, wear-os

**Summary**

I have a Wear OS app that needs to gain the user's IP address through a text input box. The issue I'm having is the user input in the keyboard does not match the text in the box once the input is finished. So during typing, the extra decimals are not shown. Once the check mark is hit, dismissing the keyboard, the text in the input box has those decimals. Please see gif below if this does not make sense.

**AVD Config**

```
Name: Wear_OS_Round_API_28

CPU/ABI: Wear OS Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\user\.android\avd\Wear_OS_Round_API_28_1.avd

Target: android-wear [Wear OS] (API level 28)

Skin: AndroidWearRound360x360

SD Card: 512M

fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: wear_round_360

hw.lcd.width: 360

hw.rotaryInput: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 28

tag.id: android-wear

hw.mainKeys: yes

hw.camera.front: emulated

avd.ini.displayname: Wear OS Round API 28

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.ramSize: 512

PlayStore.enabled: true

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.cpu.ncore: 4

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 360

vm.heapSize: 32

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-28\android-wear\x86\

hw.keyboard.lid: yes

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: virtualscene

AvdId: Wear_OS_Round_API_28

hw.lcd.density: 240

hw.arc: false

hw.device.hash2: MD5:964d285643de951626a3e8ed7682a058

fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no

fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Wear OS

runtime.network.latency: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 2G

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

**Edit Text XML Config**

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="IP Address"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:digits="0123456789."
            />
```

[image]

Comment: Number input type only has one decimal point. You'll have to use text and write/or use a library that handles IP address input

Comment: I assume its just a bug that displays the extra then? Seems kinda  backwards for it to not show, and then show it. Also, with your suggested method, is it possible to retain the numeric keypad layout? Being a wear os app, it'd be very cumbersome to use the normal keyboard layout.

Comment: Good point regarding watch UI/UX. Might want to check existing Android WearOS bugs.